# Execute a script (or program) at startup on raspberry pi

Tags: boot

I would appreciate some help as I have read a dozen answers and have failed on all of them to
run my program or script at boot.

I am running Buster Lite (no Gui)
I have a program I wrote in C++ called myProg in //myFolder.  It draws to the frame buffer.
after logging in (as pi) I can run this program by typing "//myFolder/mpProg"
I also have a script that runs this program myScript.sh
I can run myProg and myScript.sh (thus they are executable)

I have tried putting //myFolder/myProg and //myFolder/myScript.sh before the exit 0 in rc.local.
The raspi boots but does not run my program in either case.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.  thanks,
Richard

Comment: while what you've attempted to achieve using `rc.local` is obsolete, it still should work. Perhaps your program is wrong ... or maybe the path ... why do you always refer to the path with `//` at the beginning? perhaps the issue is because `It draws to the frame buffer` - but without any sort of detail, the answer is a pineapple

Comment: Does the program should always run as a service, or does it regular finished after a short time?

Answer (score 1):

As @Milliways has pointed out in his answer, `systemd` is likely the more robust of your options. However, it's not the easiest or quickest. By that I only mean that if you're not familiar with `systemd`, getting on top of the learning curve can take some time. I'd encourage you to do that (use `systemd`), but there's no reason you can't make this work with an easier and quicker method **now**, and study `systemd` in the background.

All that said, my answer is that you use `cron` (specifically the `cron` daemon (`crond`) for this task. Know beforehand that `cron` has some idiosyncrasies that may trip you up, depending upon what exactly it is that your program does. I'll try to cover some of those - let's begin:

#### 1. Define your job in your `crontab`:

Open a terminal window (probably ssh in your case), and enter these commands:

```bsh
man crontab
```

This will explain what a `crontab` is, and roughly how to use it. While you're reading, `man cron` may also be helpful. When you finish reading, simply enter the single letter `q` from the keyboard to get back to the command prompt. Next:

```bsh
crontab -e
```

This will open your `crontab` file in an editor. If you've not used it before, you may be prompted by the system to select an editor from a list. I'd recommend you select `nano` unless you have other preferences.

When the editor opens, you will probably see some text in the file which is all comments (`#` in first column). Move your insertion point to a blank line below the comments, and enter this:

```bsh
@reboot (sleep 10; /home/pi/myScript.sh) >> /home/pi/cronjoblog.txt 2>&1
```

Here's the breakdown:

`@reboot` : run when the RPi boots

`sleep 10` : wait for 10 seconds before running the next command

`/home/pi/myScript.sh` : run the script which is located in your (pi's) home dir

`>> /home/pi/cronjoblog.txt` : send all output (`stdout`) to this logfile

`2>&1` : add `stderr` (error messages) to `stdout`; all output from your program that would have gone to your terminal (`stderr` and `stdout`) is merged for inclusion in the logfile created above.

#### 2. Test

Reboot your RPi. If this doesn't work (or even if it does) check the logfile at `/home/pi/cronjoblog.txt` for clues.

Let us know if you have questions, and/or revise your question to add details.